# Access unreachable foot of server rack?

Tags: rack

I have a server rack that is in the corner.  Pushed it there with the installed casters.  Instructions seem to be to raise the rack off the casters using the adjustable feet.  Problem is I can't reach the far back foot as this rack is in a corner.  Anyone have ideas how to adjust the bolt on this foot to raise it to the same level I do with the other three? Some kind of extension?

Thanks.

JR

Comment: Note mine is similar to this where one bolt is attached to the foot bottom for adjusting, the other for locking it in place: http://vboz.net/media/u-vboz_castor_wheels_and_leveling_feet_1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rack is pushed into a corner, how do you access the back of the servers?

A few options come to mind:

1. Can you take off the side panel and reach the corner foot from the side?
2. Further to #1, many racks are open on the bottom, so if you remove some equipment from the bottom of the rack, does that make it possible to reach the foot either from the side or the front?
3. If it were me, I'd empty the rack*, lower either that foot or both of the back feet, shove it into the corner with the back feet dragging (which would only be for a short distance), and then adjust the front feet.

<sub>(*Actually, if it were me I'd do the shoving with the rack loaded up, but it'd be easier if it were empty.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Excellent suggestions.  I'm thinking of going your item 3 with the rack loaded.  Reality is I only have to have the feet down to either just alleviate the weight on the casters (i.e. still touching but barely) or barely lift them off the ground.  If I can move the rack and pull a little on the top to relieve a bit of pressure on that corner, the short distance I'd have to move it, shouldn't be a big deal.